# Nesting TrueCrypt File Volumes

Tags: windows, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption

Is it possible to nest TrueCrypt file volumes?

In other words, if I create a TrueCrypt volume as a file and store it inside another TrueCrypt file volume, will it work?

<sub>*(As for what I'm going to store there, I don't know; I'm just experimenting with TrueCrypt.)*</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work.

But you should take a look at this page regarding hidden volumes - http://www.truecrypt.org/hiddenvolume